# Site connecting through tor browser but blocked in other browser

Tags: tor

I am trying to access a website which is blocked by ISP. When using tor browser integrated with tor browser bundle, I am able to access the website. But when I am using 127.0.0.1:9150 socks proxy setting in firefox, the ISP is able to detect the URL and blocking it. How to access the website from browser other than tor browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually I was using ISP's DNS server. Tor browser has remote_dns property as true so it uses some other dns server while this property was false in Firefox. Hence the request from firefox to resolve hostname to ISP's dns server was blocked. When I set this property true in firefox, it was not blocking the site then.

- Go to **about:config** in firefox
- Search for **network.proxy.socks_remote_dns** and set it **true**